# How can I regex this tetxt in the txt file?

Tags: python

I have a txt file like this

```
DistinguishedName : CN=2,OU=2,OU=2,OU=3,OU=4,OU=5,OU=a,OU=1,OU=8,OU9,DC=a
                    ,DC=f
Enabled           : True
GivenName         : 
LastLogonDate     : 2021/7/8 AM 07:41:01
Name              : Ken
ObjectClass       : user
ObjectGUID        : r7h733-13
PasswordLastSet   : 2021/7/5 PM 10:25:08
SamAccountName    : hs875
SID               : t-1-7
Surname           : Ken
UserPrincipalName : 456
Whencreated       : 2018/1/14 PM 11:13:44


DistinguishedName : CN=1,OU=2,OU=2,OU=3,OU=4,OU=5,OU=6,OU=7,OU=8,OU9,DC=10
                    ,DC=11
Enabled           : True
GivenName         : 
LastLogonDate     : 2021/7/8 AM 07:41:01
Name              : eddie
ObjectClass       : user
ObjectGUID        : 67545-abc-98
PasswordLastSet   : 2021/7/5 PM 10:25:08
SamAccountName    : hs1234
SID               : S-1-5-21-3591743293-2469172948-1619552477-59604
Surname           : eddie
UserPrincipalName : 123
Whencreated       : 2018/1/14 PM 11:13:44
```

I want to parse this text by regex to dataframe, the columns name is before :,the value is after :
like this:

```
 DistinguishedName                                           Enabled  ... Whencreated   
 CN=2,OU=2,OU=2,OU=3,OU=4,OU=5,OU=a,OU=1,OU=8,OU9,DC=a,DC=f   True    ... 2018/1/14 PM 11:13:44
 CN=1,OU=2,OU=2,OU=3,OU=4,OU=5,OU=6,OU=7,OU=8,OU9,DC=10,DC=11 True    ... 2018/1/14 PM 11:13:44
```

How can I do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the following pattern:

```py
import re
pattern = re.compile(r'^(\w+)\s*: (.*)$')
```

Roughly, this means: from the start of the line (`^`), get the first non-empty word (`(\w+)`), ignore the trailing whitespace (`\s*`), a colon (`:`) and a space ( ), and get everything (`(.*)`) until the end of the line (`$`).

Then, just open your file and parse it to a dictionary:

```py
data = {}
with open('file.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        match = pattern.match(line)
        if not match:
            # If this line does not match, add it to the previous added line
            data[col][-1] += line.strip()
            continue
    
        col = match.group(1)
        val = match.group(2)
        data.setdefault(col, []).append(val)
```

The contents of `data` will be

```
{'DistinguishedName': ['CN=2,OU=2,OU=2,OU=3,OU=4,OU=5,OU=a,OU=1,OU=8,OU9,DC=a,DC=f',
                       'CN=1,OU=2,OU=2,OU=3,OU=4,OU=5,OU=6,OU=7,OU=8,OU9,DC=10,DC=11'],
 'Enabled': ['True', 'True'],
 'GivenName': ['', ''],
 'LastLogonDate': ['2021/7/8 AM 07:41:01', '2021/7/8 AM 07:41:01'],
 'Name': ['Ken', 'eddie'],
 'ObjectClass': ['user', 'user'],
 'ObjectGUID': ['r7h733-13', '67545-abc-98'],
 'PasswordLastSet': ['2021/7/5 PM 10:25:08', '2021/7/5 PM 10:25:08'],
 'SID': ['t-1-7', 'S-1-5-21-3591743293-2469172948-1619552477-59604'],
 'SamAccountName': ['hs875', 'hs1234'],
 'Surname': ['Ken', 'eddie'],
 'UserPrincipalName': ['456', '123'],
 'Whencreated': ['2018/1/14 PM 11:13:44', '2018/1/14 PM 11:13:44']}
```

You can transform it into a DataFrame by using

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```